# PHP APC - Any alternative or manual process in shared hosting?

Tags: php, performance, drupal, shared-hosting, apc

In shared GoDaddy hosting, PHP APC is not installed. Is there an alternative for APC if it is not installed in server. Is there any manual process there like compiling php etc. Please suggest any alternative for APC for performance.

FYI - Im going to use Drupal Boost for my site for performance.

Comment: With shared hosting you will have no way to recompile PHP with APC or any other option like it.  Also, the biggest factor with Drupal load times is the configuration and optimization of the installation.  While not APC, we do offer mod_pagespeed: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6432/which-modpagespeed-functions-do-you-support?locale=en

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to this is that with the current PHP core libraries there is little that you can directly do. The main benefit of opcode caching is from a server perspective increasing the number of requests/sec that a given server can fulfil.  However, its worth while realising that the main delay on a shared host is not actually compiling the PHP source code but in the assembly time taken by the scripts to read in all of the source files.

Shared hosts such as Godaddy use a NFS mounted NAS backend to serve the user directory space to a farm of webservers.  I don't know what the `acregmin` for the Godaddy set-up is but this is typically ~15 secs, so it is unlikely that your Drupal script files will be VFAT-cached on the webserver executing your request, and so each file open/read/close will require off-server RPC traffic.

One technique that I have adopted for my shared-service phpBB sites is to aggregrate bundles of common modules into lumped source files, which significantly reduces the number of physical I/O per request (typically halving phpBB response time.) and which I describe in more detail [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-53) if you are interested.